# Entity Framework Secondary Level Includes in Projections

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm wanting to retrieve a set of objects (`A`) and a number of related objects (`B`) within a single query. There are no navigation properties on `A` and `B` so I believe I need to use this syntax:

```cs
select a from db.As where a.Id = x select new AndBHolder
{
   A = a,
   Bs = select b from db.Bs where b.ASomeId == A.SomeId select b
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it does work. However I now need to include a property of `B` (a list of `Cs`). I wasn't expecting it to work but I tried:

```cs
select a from db.As where a.Id = x select new AndBHolder
{
   A = a,
   Bs = select b from db.Bs.Include("Cs") where b.ASomeId == A.SomeId select b
}
```

Which fails with "Method ... Include declared on type ... cannot be called with instance of type ...". Next I thought I'd try a projection within a projection:

```cs
select a from db.As where a.Id = x select new AndBHolder
{
   A = a,
   Bs = select b from db.Bs where b.ASomeId == A.SomeId select new B
        {
           Id = b.Id,
           // ...
           Cs = select c from db.Cs where c.BId == b.Id select c
        }
}
```

Which fails with "The entity or complex type '`B`' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query" because you are not allowed to project into a mapped object. So how do I retrieve the `Bs` with their `Cs` populated, or is the secondary level inclusion just not supportted? Am I just going to have to make two calls to the database, one to retrieve the As and one to retrieve the `Bs` with their `Cs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a projection with `select new` you can't use `Include` anymore, it will be ignored. Instead you must add the related entities to the projected data, for example:

```
var query = from a in db.As
            join b in db.Bs on a.SomeId equals b.ASomeId into bGroup
            where a.Id = x
            select new AndBHolder
            {
                A = a,
                Bs = bGroup, // Bs must be of type IEnumerable<B>
                Cs = bGroup.SelectMany(bg => bg.Cs) // Cs is IEnumerable<C>
            };
```

If the relationship between `B` and `C` is one-to-many (not many-to-many) EF should populate the `Cs` collection in every loaded `B` automatically (that's called "relationship fixup") which means that you could throw away the `Cs` from the projection after the data have be loaded from the database. To put this together you can try to write the query like so:

```
var query = (from a in db.As
             join b in db.Bs on a.SomeId equals b.ASomeId into bGroup
             where a.Id = x
             select new
             {
                 A = a,
                 Bs = bGroup,
                 Cs = bGroup.SelectMany(bg => bg.Cs)
             })
             .AsEnumerable() // DB query gets executed here
             .Select(y => new AndBHolder
             {
                 A = y.A,
                 Bs = y.Bs // the Cs in every B should be populated here
             });
```

Comment: Thank you Slauma, I knew Include was never going to be the answer, but I can see where I was going wrong now... using into and SelectMany has solved the issue.